# Using Sequelize Operators with values from JSON body

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

New to Sequelize and SQL queries in general but wondering there is a simple way to use values sent in JSON body from the client when querying the database. I tried a number of variations of the below without success.

A simple example of the server route looks like this:

```
builder.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let track_criteria1 = req.body.criteria1;
  let track_criteria2 = req.body.criteria2;
  const customPlaylist = await req.context.models.Song.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: [
        { criteria1: { [Op.gt]: track_criteria1 } }, 
        { criteria2: { [Op.gt]: track_criteria2 } }
    ]}
  });

  return res.send(customPlaylist);
});

module.exports = builder;
```

For context, the request from the client looks like this:

```
  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    updateStatus(PENDING) 
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/playlistbuilder/`, {
      method: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        criteria1: state.trackCriteria.criteriaOne,
        criteria2: state.trackCriteria.criteriaTwo,
      })
    }) 
      const tracks = await response.json()
      setcustomTracks(tracks)
    setTimeout(()  =>  {
      updateStatus(SUCCESS)
    },  2000)
  }
```

Maybe this is wishful thinking! Right now there is no error but the SQL query logs out like: WHERE ("songs"."criteria1" > NULL AND "songs"."criteria2" > NULL);

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else ends up here. I solved it by moving the contentType into a header. The updated submit handler looks like:

```
  const handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    updateStatus(PENDING) 
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/playlistbuilder/`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        criteria1: state.trackCriteria.criteriaOne,
        criteria2: state.trackCriteria.criteriaTwo,
      }),
    })
```

I don't know enough about this yet to explain WHY this works. I'll research that tomorrow, but it is now working.